# How to get values of all Checked checkboxes in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I am using App script which takes HTML form input & writes it into Google Sheet.

I am running it on form submit as below:

```
google.script.run
           .appscriptfunc();
```

While I'm able to get the value of selected Radio option by:

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='radioname']:checked").val()
```

I am getting the value of ONLY first checked option of the checkbox by:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='checkboxname']:checked").val()
```

HTML of checkbox:

```
<div><input id="pos1" class="validate" name="Position" required="required" type="checkbox" value="abc">abc</div>
<div><input id="pos2" class="validate" name="Position" required="required" type="checkbox" value="xyz">xyz</div>
<div><input id="pos3" class="validate" name="Position" required="required" type="checkbox" value="pqr">pqr</div>
```

How to get the values of all checked options as a string (preferably a comma-separated string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the checked checkboxes and collect the values in an array by pushing it into it.

```js
var values = [];
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='Position']:checked").each(function(i, e) {
  values.push(e.value);
});
console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input id="pos1" class="validate" name="Position" required="required" type="checkbox" value="abc">abc</div>
<div><input id="pos2" class="validate" name="Position" required="required" type="checkbox" value="xyz" checked="true">xyz</div>
<div><input id="pos3" class="validate" name="Position" required="required" type="checkbox" value="pqr">pqr</div>
```

Comment: Even this works as well - 

$("input[type='checkbox'][name='Position']:checked").map(function() { return this.value; }).get().join(",");

Answer (score 1):

How about this? If you checked "abc" and "xyz" and push the submit button, `{Position: ["abc", "xyz"]` is returned.

#### GAS

```
function myFunction(e) {
  Logger.log(e.Position) // ["abc", "xyz"] if you ckecked "abc" and "xyz"
}
```

#### HTML

```
<form>
<div><input id="pos1" class="validate" name="Position" required="required" type="checkbox" value="abc">abc</div>
<div><input id="pos2" class="validate" name="Position" required="required" type="checkbox" value="xyz">xyz</div>
<div><input id="pos3" class="validate" name="Position" required="required" type="checkbox" value="pqr">pqr</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.myFunction(this.parentNode);" />
</form>
```

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.