# Display selected checkbox values in an HTML using javascript/ google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a Select Element which creates Checkbox dropdown elements based on the items on the Google sheet.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="multiselect form-group">
<div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
<select class="form-control" >
<option>Select an option</option>
</select>
<div class="overSelect" ></div>
</div>
<div id="checkboxes">
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", afterLoad);
document.getElementById("checkboxes").addEventListener("change", loadDisplayPos);

function afterLoad(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadPosApp).checkPosApp();
}

function loadPosApp(postOpen){

   postOpen.forEach(function(r){
     
   var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
   checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
   checkbox.value = r[0];
 
   var label = document.createElement('label')
   label.appendChild(checkbox);
   label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" " + r[0]));
  
   var content = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
   content .appendChild(label);
   });
}

function loadDisplayPos(){
  var contentCheck = document.getElementById('checkboxes').value;
  console.log(contentCheck);
}

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}

</script>
```

Here is my Google Apps Script function:

```
function checkPosApp()
{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("VacantPositions_Data");
  //const myDates = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var postOpen = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  Logger.log(postOpen)
  return postOpen;
}
```

Upon the load of the Web App, it will load the values from the Google sheet to the Web App as dropdown checkboxes. My problem is how to display the checked items to the Select Element as selected. I tried to get the value of the element ID "checkboxes" but it says undefined. Do you have any suggestions or advice? I am still trying to look for a solution. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get values of all Checked checkboxes in Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892554/how-to-get-values-of-all-checked-checkboxes-in-google-app-script)

Comment: @ale13 thank you for your suggestion. I checked it and it is in jquery. I'm not familiar with jquery since I'm just new in programming. I will try the suggestions in the link you provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the idea on how to answer my problem in this link: https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/checkbox/group.php. I just modified it in a way that I could get all the checked/ selected in an array then display it in the Web App

Here is the modified function in javascript.

```
function loadDisplayPos(){
  var element = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
  var tops = element.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var tags = [];

  for (var i=0, len=tops.length; i<len; i++) {
    if ( tops[i].type === 'checkbox' ) {
      if (tops[i].checked){
         tags.push( tops[i].value);
        }
    }
}
 var selectedPost = document.getElementById('posapp').innerHTML= tags;

}
```